# MVC 4 code file (.cs) redirect to an action

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a .cs file where I am checking the session values.
I am using session like below

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["usrprof"]
```

It is written in a simple .cs file.
I can use if I am in controller but can I use it in normal .cs file
Can I use redirect to action if I don't get anything in the Session

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["usrprof"] == null)
//redirect to action.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Redirect from Response object

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["usrprof"] == null)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Controller/Action");
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Session` in your CS files, yes as long as you have access to the `Session` object.

To use `RedirectoAction` you can do:

```
public ActionResult TestMethod()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["usrprof"] == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Which will check if `usrprof` is `null`, if it is redirect them to `Index` (Or your view).  Else if `userprof` is not `null`, return the default view.

Comment: I have created a separate class file to handle all the session values. Now can I use RedirectToAction("") in that .cs file?

Comment: @Shekhar - it's generally a bad idea to do that.  Why?  Because you now have "spaghetti code".  if you start getting redirected deep in some call tree, you may not be able to easily figure out where it's doing it.  This is why you should follow the "one entrance, one exit" rule of software development.  If you need to redirect, then send something back up the call chain to notify the action method to redirect.

Comment: @MystereMan you are right. But I wanted to create a static class for accessing all the session variable. Rather than using it on individual controller action. Can I use `RedirectToRoute` in my condition?

Comment: @Shekhar maybe a better way to do this would be to either put it in a base controller you derive from or as an extensions method for controllers.

Comment: @Shekhar - No, RedirectToAction is an ActionResult, and it can only work when returned from your Controller Action method.  You could return a RedirectToAction up the call chain, and then have your action method return that, but that would mean that your code has to reference MVC assemblies.. which may be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current` is a static available to all code - will be null when not run under a web context i.e. a web app.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect from `cs` file you have to redirect from response object as shown in below piece of code

```
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(~/Account/Login, true);
```

In the above code Account is `Controller` name is Login is `Action`